# How to expose an opaque pointer in nanobind?

Tags: python, c++, nanobind

I have a function in C++ that I am trying to expose in Python:

```
void f(T* t) {
  ...
}
```

and I am wrapping it like so:

```
m.def("f", f);
```

Nanobind doesn't like the pointer and complains with:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct T’
> return nb_type_get(&typeid(Type), src.ptr(), flags, cleanup,

It seems I am trying to expose an opaque pointer, which in Boost.Python would be done like this:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_OPAQUE_SPECIALIZED_TYPE_ID(T);
```

and as far as I can see, the equivalent functionality in nanobind is:

```
NB_MAKE_OPAQUE(T);
```

The discussion [here](https://github.com/wjakob/nanobind/discussions/11) says to create a thin wrapper for `T` and it will work, but this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/2770) post explains that you create a `nb::capsule` to hold it, and then you pass `capsule::data()` which is the raw pointer to the function all within a lambda:

```
m.def("f", [](nb::capsule cap) { f((T*)cap.data()); });
```